# How do apps remember users?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I store all user info on Firebase Firestore for my SNS App. 
The app needs user id in order to access Firestore data.
When the user closes and re-opens the app, how should the id be stored?

Comment: Store it in the key chain

Comment: That's actually precisely what Firebase Authentication does: it stores the information about the user authentication state, and credentials, in the keychain, and then automatically restores the authentication state (refreshing the user's token if needed) when the app restarts.

Comment: @frank I’m actually working on authentication right now too. Does it save to keychain automatically, or do I have to set that up too? I’ll go check the documents again as well.

Comment: The save and restore happens automatically. If you're having trouble detecting it in your code, have a look at the *first* snippet here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user